# Python/Jupyter getting a FileNotFoundError when attempting to read an excel file however said file is in the correct directory

Tags: python

`data = pd.read_excel("ETH-USD")`

I continually receive an error message informing me  that the file cannot be found
this is despite the fact that

1: my directory has been changed within to Python to the same address as the folder where the excel file is stored

2: the file name is input exactly as displayed

Any ideas on why it is unable to find my file?

Comment: what's your `import os; os.getcwd()`

Comment: how would i be able tho check what my import os; is?

Comment: I meant check your current working directory. you can check it with `os.getcwd()` function. like a `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: ahh ok, when i use print(os.getcwd() ) i get the path for the folder in which i have saved my file, this is my issue i dont understand why the file cant be found if its saved in my current working directory

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the excel file has an extension of `.xlsx`, but your file explorer is set to "hide file extensions"? Try:

```
data = pd.read_excel("ETH-USD.xlsx")
```

Or, see what's in the current directory by running:

```
import os

print(os.listdir())
```

---

A tip from the comments:

> Windows tip too: hold Shift, right click the excel file and copy as path, then you can see its path (if you don't enable viewing file extensions in the file browser). –
> [creanion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7967588/creanion)

Comment: Windows tip too: hold *Shift*, right click the excel file and copy as path, then you can see its path (if you don't enable viewing file extensions in the file browser).

Comment: ok so i used print(os.listdir()) and it listed the file that im looking to read so i know its in the right place. You were correct it has an xlsx after it. However when even when i typed in the file name with the xlsx after it i still get the same file not found error as previous

Comment: @creanion Thanks! Can I quote you in the answer?

Comment: @StephenMcEneaney Can you provide a screenshot of your directory?

Comment: @AnnZen sure do you mean the folder in which ive downlaoded the files or do you mean a screenshot of what im looking at within Jupyter lab right now?

Comment: @StephenMcEneaney A screenshot of the xlsx file with the python file in the same folder.

Comment: sure, go ahead with that

Answer (score 0):

Often when running python scripts from compilers the "working directory", or where you are running the script from doesn't match the location of your script, hence why I find it much more reliable to use this instead:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"ETH-USD")
```

To add, while I do not use Jupyter, in VSCode which I use, the working directory (which is where python looks for if you put a path in `read_excel()` but its not a full path) is often the current directory opened in there, so I expect a similar issue to be the reason for your issue.